# How to implement Single Sign On (SSO) in angular 2 apps with Identity server 4?

Tags: asp.net-core, single-sign-on, angular2-services, identityserver4

I am developing some angular 2.x based application with Identity Server 4 (in asp.net core) as authentication server. Server setup, application authentication is done but now requirement is to support SSO to avoid login in each application.

To do so I am storing authentication token in local storage  and trying to reuse in different angular 2 application but it does not work.

What is the standard way to do SSO here with Identity server 4 and any types of clients with any browser?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You should not reuse same authentication token(access token) from both apps. You need to configure two clients(implicit flow will be suitable for this) in identity server and use those clients in your angular apps(one client for each). Both apps will redirect users to same identity server log-in page. When you signed into identity server(from any app) you do not require to sign-in again from the other app.

Comment: Hi rawel, I believe this but in our case somehow its not working, its redirecting to login for each app when open first time.

Comment: redirection to identity server should happen, but you should not be allowed to enter credentials when the user is already logged into identity server. You must have somehow lost the session cookie of the identity server.